# ASP.NET + JQuery 3.5.1: $(input[name=group]:radio) doesn't work but $('.group') does fire on change

Tags: jquery

I have a group of radio buttons that I need to track an onChange event.

In JSFiddle, the following code works for both change events.  But in my ASP.NET project, I can only get the change to fire if I use a class selector.

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input opmode" type="radio" name="opMode" runat="server" id="opModeFull" />
  <label class="form-check-label">Full</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input opmode" type="radio" name="opMode" runat="server" id="opModeMinimal" />
  <label class="form-check-label">Minimal</label>
</div>
```

JQuery 3.5.1:

```
//Doesn't work
$('input[name=opMode]:radio').change(function() {
  alert('changed');
});

//Works
$('.opmode').change(function() {
  alert('works');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On closer inspection, it looks like ASP.NET will change the 'name' attribute if runat='server' is added and the page is using a Master page.

When viewing the browser source it changes the name from 'opMode' to 'ctl00$BaseMaster$opMode', thus preventing input[name=opMode]:radio from firing.

I don't see a way to prevent the name change so the class selector is the workaround solution.